# How to split array in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I had a value in Cells(1,1) as below:

```
**[[{"Name":Ashwin ,"Age":64}],[],[{"Name":Shakur ,"Age":64,"Gender":Male}]]**
```

Since it has various i need to print last array element.
My expected output as below
**{"Name":Shakur ,"Age":64,"Gender":Male}**

Here my code :

```
set ws=worksheets("sheet1")
jsontext=worksheets("sheet1").cells(1,1)
set Jsonobject=JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsontext)

for each Item in Jsonobject
 if Item="Gender" then 
 end if
next
```

Cells(1,1) has the above **[[{"Name":Ashwin ,"Age":64}],[],[{"Name":Shakur ,"Age":64,"Gender":Male}]]**

When am running the above loop,it was failed due to "[[" in starting.I removed it in cell and run it ,it will considered only {"Name":Ashwin ,"Age":64}.I need to loop until 3rd array...So i tried to split up into array wise and tried to run it in code

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service - please post what you have tried so far, and we can help you improve on it.

Comment: You tell us what you want to achieve but neither what you tried, what difficulties you encountered nor are you asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExampleSplit()
Dim s As String, vx() As String
s = "**[[{""Name"":Ashwin ,""Age"":64}],[],[{""Name"":Shakur ,""Age"":64,""Gender"":Male}]]**"
vx = Split(s, "{")
MsgBox "{" & Split(vx(UBound(vx)), "}")(0) & "}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked as expected......I need to display  only the gender value in Dictionary means how we can specify.Now i need to display the value "male" only

Comment: This should be a new question? But you could try first on similar approach by yourself